# How to recompile my xorg-server in ArchLinux

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, compiling

I installed catalyst, so I needed to downgrade to xorg-server-1.11 from xorg-server-1.12. Now I use the [xorg111] repo and I understood that because of the udev, which works for the new xorg-server I have to recompile it. I don't really know how to recompile it so it works with it.

Q: How do I do the manual compilation?

Here is the thread in [Arch forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142466) if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution A: use ARM

Find and download proper packages here (also dependencies) , and use `pacman -U XX.xz` to rollback

[`http://arm.konnichi.com/search/index.php?a=32&q=xorg-server&core=1&extra=1&community=1`](http://arm.konnichi.com/search/index.php?a=32&q=xorg-server&core=1&extra=1&community=1)

### Solution B:  bulid from source

Clone this repository:

`git://pkgbuild.com/aur-mirror.git`

And find the old version of package you need , and use `makepkg` to build the Arch package , and install them with `pacman -U XX.xz`

Get ready for damaging your system ;-P

Comment: I don't see the need to clone the entire AUR to rebuild two packages, neither of which is (or probably has been) in AUR. One is from the catalyst repo and the second (the input driver) he can get from [ARM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrade_packages#ARM)

Comment: Any ideas where I could find the xorg-server-1.11.4-2 package so I can build it?

Comment: As I suggested in my comment above: [ARM has 1.11.4-1](http://arm.konnichi.com/search/index.php?a=32&q=xorg-server&core=1&extra=1&community=1)

Comment: @jasonwryan you should put that as an answer , it's better than building from source

Comment: @warl0ck I'm happy for you to add it to yours...

Comment: @jasonwryan sure